# Can't Open Fragment when clicked button

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I have created 2 fragment and their layout,
when i click button on profile fragment it should open flat layout, but
it force stop application and its not opening the second fragment,
i have included fragment code and its layout code..

> profilefragment.java

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {
View rootView;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile, container, false);

    Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            onButtonClicked(v);
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
public void onButtonClicked(View view)
{
    //do your stuff here..
    final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.button, new flatview(), "NewFragmentTag");
    ft.commit();
}
```

> profile.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}"
android:id="@+id/semester">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

> flatview.java

```
public class flatview extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.flat, container, false);
}
```

> flat.xml

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="second fragement"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

logcat

```
06-19 07:57:56.945  26457-26457/com.idealdeveloper.saltechnical E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.idealdeveloper.saltechnical, PID: 26457
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:917)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: I think the Exception is pretty clear , ClassCastException you're making an illegal casting of a Button item to ViewGroup

Comment: Don't you have a closing </RelativeLayout> tag in your profile.xml ?

Comment: Can you explain it ?? I am new to Android..

Comment: @Adhik Joshi , try my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this I guess it will work for you

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}"
android:id="@+id/semester">
<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="New Button"
android:id="@+id/fragmentLayout"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
 <Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="New Button"
android:id="@+id/button"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Class

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {
  View rootView;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {

rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile, container, false);

Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        onButtonClicked(v);
    }
});
return rootView;
 }
  public void onButtonClicked(View view)
  {
   //do your stuff here..
   final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
   ft.add(R.id.fragmentLayout, new flatview(), "NewFragmentTag");
   ft.commit();
   }
```

I hope this one will helps you

Comment: Now, M Not Getting Any Error or Force Stop When Click, But When Button Clicked Its Not Opening Or Changing  Fragment, Its Stays Where It Is...

Comment: this is just works fine.. and fragment changed...  but the fragment button is overlapping with other fragment... i Have tried to add white back ground but its not working.. i have linked project https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BykGyq2bS2o9ZjBzYklVeDNTZXc/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

The fragment transaction inserts a `View` into a `ViewGroup`, so you can't just replace a `Button`. You could just replace the parent `semester`, since it is a `ViewGroup`.

```
public void onButtonClicked(View view) {
    final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.semester, new flatview(), "NewFragmentTag");
    ft.commit();
}
```

If your intention is also to remove the button, you will need to do it manually since the `FragmentManager` can only modify runtime transactions:

```
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.semester);
parent.removeView(view);
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to provide a `ViewGroup` root for the flat.xml layout , for example you can surround the `TextView` with a `LinearLayout`

flat.xml :

```
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
               android:text="second fragement"
               android:id="@+id/textView3"
               android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```